# Where do I put all these function-like #defines, in C?

Tags: c, include, embedded, c-preprocessor, code-organization

I'm working with an embedded system, and I'm ending up with a ton of HW-interfacing `#define` macros.  I want to put all of these into a separate file (for OOP-ness), but I don't know the best way to `#include` that.  Do I just put them all into a .c file, then include that?  Seems silly to put these in a .h file.

Comment: FWIW: Those are called "macros", not "functions".

Comment: Why does it seem silly to put them all in a .h file?

Comment: @dmckee: we can split the difference and call them "function-like macros" as opposed to "object-like macros" - the terms used in the standard.

Answer (score 14):

I don't see anything wrong with the .h file.

Comment: Yep, this is standard practice.

Comment: Well, the general rule of thumb is function prototypes reside in .h files and their implementations in .c files.  In this case, I'd be putting the implementations in the .h files -- not normally where somebody would look for them.

Comment: @Tristan: what's true for functions is not necessarily true for macros; it's also common for inline functions to reside in header-files

Comment: @Tristan & Christoph:  It is quiet common to put #define MACRO's into the .h files.  These MACRO's are in-line functions.  One way I make it clear to the reader it is a MACRO and not a function is; I usually declare all my MACRO's in uppercase.

Comment: you can check the u-boot source code, that's how they do, put it in .h file and it's real clean that way

Comment: It is usually best to place HW-interfacing macros in a header file reserved for platform-specific code.  This will improve your portability, in that you can swap out a header for one hardware platform for a header for another hardware platform using a `#define` or a parameter passed to 'make'.

Answer (score 8):

These should go in the `.h` files.  The other option is a `.c` file, and that would require using `#include` to include a `.c` file, which will very definitely confuse people -- as well as confusing your makefile, if it uses the standard assumption that every `.c` file will correspond directly to a compiled `.o` file.

The normal pattern is that `.h` files are for things that are included in other places (and, particularly, in multiple other places), and that `.c` files are for things that are compiled once into object files.

Thus, the following things normally go into `.h` files:

- Function prototypes
- Constant declarations
- Global variable `extern` declarations
- Inline function definitions
- Type definitions
- and macro definitions, such as what you're asking about.

Conversely, the following things normally go into `.c` files:

- Global variable definitions
- Function definitions that will be compiled into object code and linked

The case of "function definitions only go into `.c` files" is simply the degenerate case when you don't have any inline functions.

In C++, where lots of functions are defined in templated form and thus the definitions need to be included whenever they're used, those definitions very often go in the `.h` (or `.hpp`, or whatever) file.  So this sort of thing definitely has precedent.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not necessarily recommending this but have seen it in quite a few embedded projects over the last 10+ years: include inline functions as .inl.

Brooks breaks down the responsibilities nicely. You might consider separating inline and macro definitions from ordinary function prototypes and such:

```
#include "prototypes.h"
#include "macros.inl"

int foo(void);
int bar(char);
```

Your end goal is consistency: any layout decisions should assist those who succeed you.

Answer (score 1):

Put them where you need them.

If you need it only for one file then put it at the top of that file.

If you need it for multiple files then put it in a header file.

Comment: And if defines are needed only in one function: inside the function or at the top of the file?